# How to find weekdays ago using PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime

Assuming today is 2/11/13. I want find 5 business days ago - so, that would be the 4th.

But using this code:

```
echo date("n/j/Y",strtotime("-5 weekdays"));
```

I get the 2/2/2013. However, when entering "-4 weekdays" I get 2/5/2013, which doesn't make sense.

Weekdays include M-F

Comment: Those functions seem to calculate days between for business days. I want to input a string like "5 weekdays ago" and have it display the date format of it.

Comment: Let me give this a whirl. Weekdays would be defined as M-F just for clarity?